# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string - Joomla K2 Store error after updating php to php 7.2

Tags: php, joomla3.0, php-7.2

I recently updated a Joomla site to v3.9 and running K2store for the shopping functionality.

I notice that the checkout page works fine on php7.0 but as soon as I upgrade to php7.2, it throws the error

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

My hosting provider is upgrading all their services to only support php7.2 - this is why I need to upgrade the website.

Below is the code that generates the country dropdown selection on the checkout page, which is giving the error.

```
function setValues(&$zones,&$fields,$k,&$field){

    if($field->field_type=='zone' && !empty($field->field_options['zone_type']) && $field->field_options['zone_type']=='country'){
        foreach($zones as $zone){
            $title = $zone->country_name;
            $obj = new stdClass();
            $obj->value = $zone->country_name;
            $obj->disabled = '0';
            $fields[$k]->field_value[$zone->country_id]=$obj;
        }
    } elseif($field->field_type=='zone' && !empty($field->field_options['zone_type']) && $field->field_options['zone_type']=='zone'){
        foreach($zones as $zone){
            if(isset($zone->zone_id)) {
                $title = $zone->zone_name;
                $obj = new stdClass();
                $obj->value = $title;
                $obj->disabled = '0';
                $fields[$k]->field_value[$zone->zone_id]=$obj;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error is on the `$fields[$k]->field_value[$zone->zone_id]=$obj;` on both if statements.

I'd like to understand what is causing the error in php7.2 and how I can fix it.